# IndexError in python - list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code, but I'm getting IndexError: list index out of range. And I don't really understand why. The for loop should go through all tds, starting at the second [1] td. So why is the index out of range?

```
import bs4 as bs
import pickle
import requests
import lxml

def save_OMX30_tickers():
   resp = requests.get('https://www.avanza.se/aktier/lista.html')
   soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
   table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'u-standardTable'})
   tickers = []
   for row in table.findAll('tr')[0:]:
       ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
       tickers.append(ticker)

   with open('OMX30tickers.pickle', 'wb') as f:
       pickle.dump(tickers, f)

   print(tickers)

   return tickers

save_OMX30_tickers()
```

Comment: What happens when `row.findAll('td')` finds one or less `td`? For example a row with only `th`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some times your `row.findAll('td')` is empty try this it will help, also i'd recommad you to add `rsplit()` to remove all `\n`

```
for row in table.findAll('tr')[0:]:
    if not row.findAll('td'):                                                                                                                                                 
        continue
    ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
    tickers.append(ticker.rsplit())
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how did you find that `row.findAll('td')` is sometimes empty?

Comment: `if not row.findAll('td')` means that if `row.findAll('td')` is empty we stop our for loop statement and start another for loop statment, but if `row.findAll('td')` has at least one value we get it